# Como identificar um número na tela com Bitmap?

Tags: c#, bitmap

Sou novo em C# e pretendo fazer um programa para identificar números na tela
[image: Imagem do Numero] e transforma-los ou salva-los em uma variável Double. A única coisa que consegui fazer foi tirar o print da tela :P

```
 Bitmap printtela ()
    {

        Bitmap novaleitura = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, 
        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(novaleitura);
        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);

        return novaleitura;
    }
```

Pesquisei no Youtube e tentei aptar o código desse vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEgxZrXPnzc&t=172s
Porém nem a copia do própio código do vídeo chegou a rodar corretamente :P

Comment: Você quer implementar um OCR?

Comment: Julio Borges sim.. :)

Comment: Veja se estes links te ajudam: [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) [Contour Analysis for Image Recognition in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196168/Contour-Analysis-for-Image-Recognition-in-C)

Comment: Vlw pela ajuda pessoal :)